# vapor: Address already in use (errno: 98)

Tags: swift, ubuntu, nginx, supervisord, vapor

I deployed my vapor project to Ubuntu. And made the configuration of supervisor and Nginx.

When I invoke my server. first call is success but When I try second call I get 502 bad gateway error from browser. When I check error log, the error is

```
"Fatal error: Error raised at top level: bind(descriptor:ptr:bytes:) failed: Address already in use (errno: 98) : file /home/buildnode/jenkins/wo$"
```

If I kill the port(8080) process. And after, I try to connect again first try is success then get fail again.

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: perhaps: stop vapor. check which ports are in use: `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` (Ubuntu 16.04). assign vapor instance to a unused port. also check that only one instance of vapor is launched per the assigned port.

Comment: I have the same problem with supervisor running. When I stop supervisor all works correct.

Comment: @sof98789 were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth unfortunately I cannot solve the problem. Because I had no idea, I discarded the project and use another template project that I found on github. And with that template everything works fine

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was able to fix it as described [here](https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/issues/238). I'll post that as an answer...

Comment: For Vapor 4 as mentioned in the docs of Vapor, I tried :

    `public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
            app.http.server.configuration.port = 9090
            try routes(app)
     }`

Answer (score 84):

This might be caused by another process using that  port.
I had the same issue and was able to solve it by listing all the processes on port `:8080`:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
```

and then killing all of them one by one by typing:

```
$ kill {PID of the process}
```

After that, my app built again properly.

---

<sup>taken from [here](https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/issues/238)</sup>

Comment: as I said in my question. When I kill the process on :8080 port. at first call, it works but then I get the error again whenever I call

Comment: Oh okay, that wasn't the case for me...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. This worked for me:

```
$ kill -9 {PID of the process}
```

Hope this helps!